# Finish HTTP cloud function even after user terminates

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using this code to call a Firebase HTTP Cloud Function:

```
$.post('https://...my-function', {some_data: 'Data'}).always(function (data) { });
```

If the user closes their browser, the function stops. How can I make it that even if the user exits, the function would still finish in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi that's a scenario I face every day from multiple clients - web, android and ios. Here's how we deal with it.

Using cloud function triggers. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data

When you call your http trigger, make sure to **push** (firebase.ref(node_name).push(event_value)) the event to a new node.

Like eg: ImageUploadingRequest

Write a cloud function trigger to trigger, onCreate in the **ImageUploadingRequest** node. In this way, you can maintain a queue for all the async functions to happen even after the user has closed the browser. Once your function is done, delete the event from ImageUploadingRequest node.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

It's implied, with HTTP requests, that the client is interested in the results of the work without having to make another request.  With Cloud Functions, there is no way to have an HTTP type function continue indefinitely.

If you want some work started by a client's HTTP request to survive beyond the lifecycle of the request and response, you will have to do something to invoke a second function that isn't bound to an HTTP request.

Praveen's answer describes one way to do it, but that only makes sense if you're already using Realtime Database.  It also requires you to be careful about managing the queue of work that's stored in the database.

In my opinion, it's easier to use a [Pub/Sub trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) as a followup function that actually performs the background work that continues regardless of what happens with the HTTP client.  If you use this technique, your HTTP function will do this:

1. Create a message object with the parameters needed to complete the work.
2. Send that message over pub/sub to a topic that's handled by the other function.
3. Send a response to the HTTP client indicating that the work is in progress.

Then, the pub/sub function will:

1. Receive the message event object.
2. Perform work asynchronously.
3. Return a promise indicating when all the async work is complete.